# DataSync agent ran into an error connecting to AWS

Tags: aws-datasync

We are trying to move files from EFS to EFS but they are not in the same region. We have connected the 2 VPCs in different regions with PCX and we need to create a EC2 instance hosted in source EFS as DataSync agent.

We have also created VPC Endpoint for AWS DataSync in destination VPC then create agent resource in destination region pointing to agent deployed in source region using the AWS DataSync VPC endpoint just created. However when we run the task to transfer files from source to destination EFS it fails with this error message:

```
DataSync agent ran into an error connecting to AWS. Please review the DataSync network requirements and ensure required endpoints are accessible from the agent. Please contact AWS support if the error persists.
```

We tried to allow all traffic in all related SG and the PCX is active, agent status shown in destination region is active. We have no idea on what would be wrong.

Thanks for helping